# Laravel 5.7 Guard and Middleware are not Working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel instance, the guard or middleware is not working. My admin panel is always visible auth or non-auth. I don't understand what the problem is.

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/admin', 'admin\adminController@index')->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::get('/admin-login', 'auth\adminLoginController@index');
Route::post('/admin-login', 'auth\adminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
```

**Controller**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;

class adminLoginController extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.admin-login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->Validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], false, false)) {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Invalid Information');
    }
}
```

If i delete `__construct()` , then i can visit admin log-in page , otherwise i cannot go in !!

my code of `auth.php` :

Guards :

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

],
```

**Providers**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\admin::class,
    ],
],
```

**adminController**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

class adminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user = User::all();
        $maleuser = User::where('gender', 'male')->get();
        $femaleuser = User::where('gender', 'female')->get();
        return view('admin/index')
            ->with('users', $user)
            ->with('maleusers', $maleuser)
            ->with('femaleusers', $femaleuser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your Route to look like this

```
Route::get('/admin', 'admin\adminController@index')->middleware('auth:admin');
Route::get('/admin-login', 'auth\adminLoginController@index')->middleware('guest:admin');
Route::post('/admin-login', 'auth\adminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit')->middleware('guest:admin');
```

also edit this line in your adminLoginController

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
}
```